# Select row from DataTable based on condition

Tags: c#

I am trying to use Datatable Select but I am getting incorrect data

```
 double marks = 5; 
 DataRow[] result = dsGrades.Tables[0].Select("Convert(MarksFrom, 'System.Decimal') >=" + marks + " And " + marks + "<= Convert(MarksTo, 'System.Decimal') ");
```

dsGrades contains below data,
[image]

when 'marks' contain '5.0', I am expecting row where MarksFrom = 5.0 and MarksTo = 5.9, as 5.0 falls in this range, but here it is returning 5 rows.

Whats wrong with datatable select? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are the datatypes of the `MarksFrom` and `MarksTo` columns?

Comment: Those are decimals

Comment: `double` is probably your best bet for a grading precision, if you have the ability to change the `DataTable` schema.  `decimal` is a better choice for currency.

Comment: Check my answer- getting all the rows where MarksFrom is above 5 will return the first 5 visible rows in table, checking the second condition for these 5 rows and 5.0 is less than or equal to MarksTo in each of the rows so this would evaluate true for these rows. Therefore grabbing 5 rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If would make sense to change your DataColumn types to `double`, however even with `decimal` you don't need a conversion inside the expression.

Note in your provided example, your constraint appears to be backwards.  You're specifying that you want `MarksFrom` *greater or equal* to the passed in amount, which won't return a single row in the range you want.

This should return a single row for any mark passed in:

```
double marks = 5.0; 
DataRow[] result = dsGrades.Tables[0].Select($"{marks} >= MarksFrom AND {marks} <= MarksTo");
```

Also since you're always only expecting a single match, you could change this to:

```
DataRow match = table.Select($"{marks} >= MarksFrom AND {marks} <= MarksTo").SingleOrDefault();
```

`SingleOrDefault` will throw an `InvalidOperationException` if more than one result is returned, which may be the desired outcome in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
double marks = 5.0;
decimal newMarks = Convert.ToDecimal(marks);
var result = 
     dsGrades.Tables[0]
             .AsEnumerable()
             .Where( dr => dr.Field<decimal>( "MarksFrom" ) >= newMarks 
                     && dr.Field<decimal>( "MarksTo" ) < newMarks + 1);
```

This could be the solution:

```
var result = dsGrades.Tables[0].Select("Convert(MarksFrom, 'System.Decimal') >=" + newMarks + " And Convert(MarksTo, 'System.Decimal') < " newMarks + 1);
```

From my comment on question explaining problem:

Getting all the rows where MarksFrom is above 5 will return the first 5 visible rows in table, checking the second condition for these 5 rows and 5.0 is less than or equal to MarksTo in each of the rows so this would evaluate true for these rows. Therefore grabbing 5 rows

Comment: Providing a different method doesn't explain the problem nor is it guaranteed to work.

Comment: Note the columns are `decimal`

Comment: For using `AsEnumerable` changing the `<TField>` will still require casting the variable to a `decimal` for comparison operators to work.

Comment: What is the datatype of the columns?

Comment: Yes now you've changed `marks` to a `decimal`, that will work.  However OP's original post indicates this is a `double`.

Comment: Can we not convert the double to decimal before performing the query

Comment: When using `DataRow.Field<T>` either the variable needs to be converted beforehand, or the column value if you want comparison operators to work.  What you posted earlier wouldn't compile.

Comment: Well this is returning two rows when the value is 8
Two range 8 - 8.9 and 9 - 10

Answer (score 0):

**Needs to do casting from datatable as below:**

```
   DataRow[] drGrdPercntl = dt_GrdPercntil.Select($"{SubjVal} >= Convert(MarksFrom, 'System.Decimal') AND {SubjVal} <= Convert(MarksTo, 'System.Decimal')");
```